# Toolbar item not showing

Tags: iphone, toolbar

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't have a nib so I'm making everything in loadView. The toolbar shows up but the segmentedControl does not.

```
- (void)loadView
{ 
    // Toolbar
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];
    [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 30)];
    [segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl] autorelease];

    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item, nil];

    [toolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in place of your code; this will help you to add segment control to your toolbar:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];
[toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

CGRect frame;

frame.origin.x = 10;
frame.origin.y = 10;
frame.size.width = 200;
frame.size.height = 30;

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"Hi", nil]];

[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

segmentedControl.frame = frame;

[toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I thought you had to use setItems:animated on the toolbar. What's the point of setItems:animated since this code doesn't use it?

Answer (score 0):

You've got to add it as a `subview` of the view as you did with the toolbar. I.e:

`[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];`

It should work.

Cheers